# "Ask Question" functionality: Essential details for every question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, asking-questions

Almost every question should specify the operating system(s) and whether the recommendation request is for gratis or commercial software.

Many questions fail to include this information, which then requires comments and/or flagging.

How can the "Ask Question" functionality be improved to make it explicit that certain details are essential?

Comment: Would it not be a good thing if requirement for OS and pricing is mentioned as placeholder text in the editor when the user tries to write a question. I think that would be the place where it would catch the attention of the user strongly.

Comment: @Firelord I agree.  I think that would be an excellent place.

Comment: Related: [Can/should we force users to state O/S and gratis or not before posting?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1077/60) · [Would a more rigid question template help achieve a consistent quality?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/871/60)